# Order of magnitude of $\sum \frac{1}{\log{p}}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series

**Question:** What is the order of magnitude of the following sum?

$$  \sum_{\substack{p<n\\\text{$p$ prime}}} \frac{1}{\log{p}} $$

**Additional information**: Since

$$   \sum_{\substack{p<n\\\text{$p$ prime}}} \frac{1}{\log{n}} \leq  \sum_{\substack{p<n\\\text{$p$ prime}}} \frac{1}{\log{p}}   \leq \sum_{p<n} \frac{1}{\log{p}}, $$

we have that, for some constants $c_1,c_2$,
$$c_1\frac{n}{\log^2{n}} \leq  \sum_{\substack{p<n\\\text{$p$ prime}}} \frac{1}{\log{p}} \leq c_2 \frac{n}{\log{n}}. $$

Here, the asymptotics on the left hand side came from the prime number theorem, and on the right hand side from the asymptotic expansion of the  logarithmic integral function.

(See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion)

Comment: The upper bound can be improved to $O(n/\log^2n)$ for free, simply by splitting the summation range into the two subintervals $p<\sqrt n$ and $\sqrt n<p<n$. (For the second subinterval, each summand is $O(1/\log n)$, and the number of summands is $O(n/\log n)$ by the prime number theorem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The contribution of the primes $p\leq n/\log ^3 n$ is clearly $O(n/\log^3 n)$. For the remaining primes we have
$$ \log n-3\log\log n <\log p<\log n,$$
$$ \frac{1}{\log p}=\frac{1}{\log n}+O\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log^2 n}\right), $$
so by the Prime Number Theorem their contribution is
$$ \left(\frac{n}{\log n}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log^2 n}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{\log n}+O\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log^2 n}\right)\right)=\frac{n}{\log^2 n}+O\left(\frac{n\log\log n}{\log^3 n}\right).$$
Altogether we see that
$$ \sum_{p<n} \frac{1}{\log{p}} =\frac{n}{\log^2 n}+O\left(\frac{n\log\log n}{\log^3 n}\right).$$

Better bounds can be obtained by partial summation, namely
$$ \sum_{p\leq n} \frac{1}{\log{p}} = \frac{\pi(n)}{\log n}+\int_2^n\frac{\pi(x)}{x\log^2 x}dx. $$

Comment: I was looking at this just last night. What are the odds? (Someone else can pose that as an MO question.)